# Howto receive UDP messages in Alpine docker container?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm having troubles with my container receiving UDP responses. I've tried to test this and the test already fails (using OSX):

```
~/htdocs/evcc master 17s
❯ docker run -p 7090:7090/udp -it --rm alpine
/ # nc -u -l 0.0.0.0 7090
```

and from the host:

```
~/htdocs/evcc master
❯ nc -u 0.0.0.0 7090                         
ljkhgdkfjhg
```

Yet, no echo inside the container. The same works fine when both are run on the host.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the Alpine image. I tried your commands using ubuntu and they work fine.